# Facebook iframe app and passing query

Tags: tabs, facebook-iframe

right now i have 5 apps for the same url with different query of the folder to pull the info from.
every app is then getting connected to the page.

is there a way to make 1 app and that the connecting proccess to the page on facebook will be the one that will ask for the query?

i want to make the proccess easy for me and cleaner so i won't find myself with 30+ apps when i acctually only have 15 or less

```
http://www.domain.com/facebooktabs/index.asp?folder=xxx
http://www.domain.com/facebooktabs/index.asp?folder=yyy
```

this are the url in each tab - and what i want is only one up but to be able to pass the query to the iframe from the tab on the page

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 Page tab == 1 page tab application and 1 page tab application can have only 1 url associated with it.

This is the current paradigm that Facebook has setup.  From your question, I cannot figure out why you have 2 apps per page tab.

Comment: To pass query string parameters to a page tab, just use app_data.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: The solution is working for me in production.  I'm unsure why you're unable to implement.  I pass data to the page tab app via the app_data all the time.  Works flawlessly.